# Type mismatch mapping Future[Seq[model]] using Play with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I still struggle sometimes to map Futures using Play with Scala...

I am trying to pass to a view my entire Supply DB table (i.e. all the supplies in the DB).
I have tried two distinct ways but both have failed...
Below are the methods I've tried and the errors I get.

Can someone please help me solve this, and also explain me why both of these have failed?
Thank you in advance!

**Note:** Calling `supplyService.all` returns a `Future[Seq[Supply]]`.

**First attempt**

```
  def index = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    supplyService.all map { supplies =>
      Future.successful(Ok(views.html.supplies.index(request.identity, SupplyForm.form, supplies)))
    }
  }
```

[image]

**Second attempt**

```
  def index = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    val supplies = supplyService.all

    Future.successful(Ok(views.html.supplies.index(request.identity, SupplyForm.form, supplies)))
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First variant without `Future.succesfull`

```
supplyService.all.map( supplies => Ok(views.html.supplies.index(request.identity, SupplyForm.form, supplies)) )
```

Since you have can construct function `Seq[Supply] => Result` you can easily `map` 
`Future[Seq[Supply]]` to `Future[Result]` via [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) interface.

Future is also a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) , so you can use `Seq[Supply] => Future[Result]` with `flatMap` method.

But `Future.successfull` is monad unit , and as for many monads for `Future` its true that

```
mx.flatMap(f andThen unit) = mx.map(f)
```

so your

```
ms.flatMap(supplies => Future.successfull(f(supplies)) = 
ms.flatMap(f andThen Future.successfull) = 
ms.map(f)
```

Comment: I think it is, thank you! I'm just beginning and I'm still learning, but I think your explanation will be useful in the future! Thanks again :)

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho I think it will. You can't overestimate profit of `Future` undestanding in *Play! 2*

 While *Play! 2* seems like ordinal full-stack web framework from first look, it has some pretty hardcore functional thing in its core named `Iteratees`. Whole it's asynchronous architecture is built on it and it's crucial to understand base FP theory properly to not lost your mind while understanding it. [Some cool guys leave it just because its complexity](http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2014/12/04/Farewell-Scala/) .  

A little bit Haskell experience could be a great help in such things.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for sure and learn a bit more about iteratees! Thanks for your comment and suggestions! :)